# Difficulty understanding the variational bicomplex

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, jet-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a smooth fiber bundle, with (infinite-order) jet bundle $J_\infty\rightarrow X$.

I am reading about the [variational bicomplex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/variational+bicomplex); as stated at that nLab link, it is a bicomplex structure on the de Rham complex of $J_\infty$ (regarded as an infinite-dimensional manifold).

The expression $\Omega^n(J_\infty) = \bigoplus_{h+v=n} \Omega^{h,v}$ at that link suggests that the variational bicomplex comes from some direct-sum decomposition $\Omega^1(J_\infty) = A\oplus B$ where $A,B$ respectively would be "horizontal and vertical" 1-forms, and correspond in the aforementioned notation to $(h,v)$ being $(1,0),(0,1)$ respectively.

I understand that we could take e.g. the "horizontal" 1-forms on $J_\infty$ to be the ones which vanish on $\mathrm{ker}(d\pi)$, where $\pi : J_\infty \rightarrow X$ is the projection.

However, I don't see how a choice of "vertical" 1-forms on $J_\infty$ arises. Wouldn't this be equivalent to a choice of connection on the smooth bundle $J_\infty\rightarrow X$?

---

Edit: Originally I asked about horizontal/vertical vector fields; instead I've changed the question to be about horizontal/vertical 1-forms.

Comment: There is a canonical flat connection on the infinite jet bundle which corresponds to this splitting. You can look in section 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105223 for some formulas

Comment: @AlexK I see, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to add a comment but I just made an account; so I cannot yet comment.

For a bundle $E \rightarrow X$, the space of vertical differential forms $\Omega^*_V(E)$ is defined to be the quotient of the de Rham complex $\Omega^*(E)$ by the differential ideal of horizontal forms $\Omega^*_H(E)$ which, as you noted, is canonically defined. A connection allows you to choose representatives in this quotient.

The above is for a general bundle $E$, so there is no canonical choice of representatives for the space of vertical differential forms; i.e., there is no canonical choice for $\Omega^*_V(E)$ as a subalgebra of $\Omega^*(E)$ instead of a quotient. However, as @Alex K mentioned, for the case where $E$ is the infinite jet bundle, there is a canonical flat connection.

Another reference: for the explicit construction of vertical forms in the variational bicomplex, see [Anderson, The Variational Bicomplex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/AndersonVariationalBicomplex.pdf) (pages 15 to 18 in the document's numbering, or pages 44 to 47 of the pdf). I like this exposition because it shows how the vertical and horizontal exterior derivatives arise explicitly.